# View pager height and recycler view hieght not working inside scroll view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

There is a recycler view element in the view pager that contains the random number of lists. The view pager works only if the hard coded height is specified and also the recycler view scroll acts as separate scroll along with the parent.

How can I make the recycler view scroll make a part of main activity scroll to make it a smooth scrolling experience and view pager should automatically take height as per the number of elements in the recycler view dynamically.

Please also suggest some good practice to follow which I may be doing wrong to enhance performance.

Main Layout

**dashboard_activity.xml**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.activities.settings.MyActivity">

       <!-- This is for the empty condition  -->
       <include
            layout="@layout/first_time_empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

       <!-- This layout is for the data -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout_data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- cards and other chart details -->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- cards and other chart details -->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_names_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
          />

        <!--Height of view pager is currently fixed .Have to search for solution with scrollview+viewpager-->
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="500dp" /> <!-- This is the one issue -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Recyclerview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/each_unit_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recycler view data"
        />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested scrolling is usually difficult to deal with. There are some issues that you need to figure out. RecyclerView usually needs a fixed height - If you want the height of the RecyclerView to changed based on number of items, the RecyclerView won't recycle any ViewHolders and create/draw all the views at the same time. This defeats the purpose of RecyclerView and hence it does not support `wrap_content` as its height. You should decide why you want a RecyclerView here. Is it really necessary?

Comment: ViewPager also needs a fixed height as it has multiple children and each child may have different height. So how would the ViewPager decide on its own height? There are custom implementation ViewPager where it changes its height based on the current child or max height of all children. Again, you need to ask yourself, how would you need your ViewPager to set its height if children have variable heights.

Comment: Another question for you. What is the use of the ScrollView? Do you need it? Since RecyclerView is a scrollable element (inside the ViewPager), do you require another scroll element?

Comment: The item list starts after 80 percent of the height, and its just scroll between remaining 20%, I want the ui should scroll, I don't take the scroll view it takes fixed size and half data is visible

Comment: It would be great if you could post a screenshot. Also, seems like you could use `CoordinatorLayout` here.